# How do I access views in nested layouts programmatically?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to use an `ImageView` in my java code that is inside the second `RelativeLayout` node in the XML. However, I can't get references to the `ImageViews` as seen by the `setVisibility` method that does not make the images invisible.

**[DOUBLE EDIT] Here is my revised** Activity Class:

```
package com.scopelyapplication.tictactoe;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class TicTacToeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final String LOGTAG = "TicTacToeActivity";
private ModelComputerGameHelper comHelp;

boolean humanIsX;

RelativeLayout layout;
ImageView blueX;
ImageView greyX;
ImageView blueO;
ImageView greyO;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

    Log.d(LOGTAG, "onCreate");

    //Set up action bar
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "set action bar");

    //Initialize X's and O's
    blueX = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.blueXTopLeft);
    greyX = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.greyXTopLeft);
    blueO = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.blueOTopLeft);
    greyO = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.greyOTopLeft);
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "X's and O's initialized");

    //Turn off their visibility until one is clicked.
    blueX.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //where the NPE occurs
    greyX.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    blueO.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    greyO.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    boolean gameIsPVP = extras.getBoolean("gameIsPVP");
    humanIsX = extras.getBoolean("humanIsX");

    if (gameIsPVP) {
        ; //in progress
    } else {
        startComputerGame(humanIsX);
    }
}

public void squareOneClick(View imageView) {

    char humanPlayer = ' ';
    if (humanIsX) {
        humanPlayer = 'X';
    } else {
        humanPlayer = 'O';
    }
    comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 0);
    if (humanPlayer == 'X') {
        blueX.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        blueO.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    updateBoard();
}
public void squareTwoClick(View imageView) {

    char humanPlayer = ' ';
    if (humanIsX) {
        humanPlayer = 'X';
    }
    else {
        humanPlayer = 'O';
    }
    comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 1);
    updateBoard();
}
public void squareThreeClick(View imageView) {

    char humanPlayer = ' ';
    if (humanIsX) {
        humanPlayer = 'X';
    }
    else {
        humanPlayer = 'O';
    }
    comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 2);
    updateBoard();
}
public void squareFourClick(View imageView) {

    char humanPlayer = ' ';
    if (humanIsX) {
        humanPlayer = 'X';
    }
    else {
        humanPlayer = 'O';
    }
    comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 3);
    updateBoard();
}
public void squareFiveClick(View imageView) {

    char humanPlayer = ' ';
    if (humanIsX) {
        humanPlayer = 'X';
    }
    else {
        humanPlayer = 'O';
    }
    comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 4);
    updateBoard();
}
public void squareSixClick(View imageView) {

    char humanPlayer = ' ';
    if (humanIsX) {
        humanPlayer = 'X';
    }
    else {
        humanPlayer = 'O';
    }
    comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 5);
    updateBoard();
}
public void squareSevenClick(View imageView) {

    char humanPlayer = ' ';
    if (humanIsX) {
        humanPlayer = 'X';
    }
    else {
        humanPlayer = 'O';
    }
    comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 6);
    updateBoard();
}
public void squareEightClick(View imageView) {

    char humanPlayer = ' ';
    if (humanIsX) {
        humanPlayer = 'X';
    }
    else {
        humanPlayer = 'O';
    }
    comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 7);
    updateBoard();
}
public void squareNineClick(View imageView) {

    char humanPlayer = ' ';
    if (humanIsX) {
        humanPlayer = 'X';
    }
    else {
        humanPlayer = 'O';
    }
    comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 8);
    updateBoard();
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, PickerActivity.class));
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void startComputerGame(boolean isHumanX) {
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "startComputerGame");
    comHelp = new ModelComputerGameHelper(isHumanX);
    updateBoard();
}

public void updateBoard() {
    //in progress. connects startComputerGame and Clicks with Visuals.

}

}
```

And here is some of my XML from **activity_main**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minHeight="20dp"
android:minWidth="20dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gameBoard"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/gameboard"
    android:src="@drawable/gameboard" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/squareOneLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="290dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="220dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/squareOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="288dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="219dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/top_left"
        android:onClick="squareOneClick"
        android:src="@drawable/blank_button" />

    <!-- Top-left images -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/blueOTopLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/greyOTopLeft"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/piece_o" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/greyOTopLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/piece_o_grey" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/greyXTopLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blueOTopLeft"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/piece_x_grey" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/blueXTopLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blueOTopLeft"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/piece_x" />
</RelativeLayout>

... <!-- rest of xml -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is my logcat, sorry for forgetting!

```
02-23 03:27:26.984: D/AndroidRuntime(1125): Shutting down VM
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125): Process: com.scopelyapplication.tictactoe, PID: 1125
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.scopelyapplication.tictactoe/com.scopelyapplication.tictactoe.TicTacToeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at com.scopelyapplication.tictactoe.TicTacToeActivity.onCreate(TicTacToeActivity.java:54)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
02-23 03:27:26.984: E/AndroidRuntime(1125):     ... 11 more
```

Thank You!

Comment: What line gives the NPE? Please provide a stacktrace.

Comment: directly findviewbyid...

Comment: I added the logcat, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but are you using the View IDs anywhere else in the layout?

Comment: @DeeV in the layout, no. because all the relative placement is done with the layouts, not the views. This is so, if I wanted to, I could dynamically add imageviews to each layout with the right properties, rather than placing them specifically each time.

Comment: Can you try cleaning and rebuilding the project? I'm thinking your R file is corrupt. This can happen sometimes when editing xml layouts a lot. The IDs get mixed and you end up pulling the wrong Views from the layouts. This would explain your ClassCastException.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then you can try getting the ImageViews directly by calling `View squareOne = layout.findViewById(R.id.squareOneLayout);` and then `(ImageView) blueX = (ImageView) squareOne.findViewById(R.id.blueXTopLeft);`. If you can get them like that, then that narrows down the problem. Nothing pops out at me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue lies within your layout XML. See the documentation for [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) which states:

> Note that you cannot have a circular dependency between the size of the RelativeLayout and the position of its children. For example, you cannot have a RelativeLayout whose height is set to WRAP_CONTENT and a child set to ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM.

You need to correct the circular dependency in squareOneLayout (and possibly elsewhere as well).

A RelativeLayout cannot size itself based on the size of its children, if you want the children to be positioned relative to the parent RelativeLayout.

To put it another way, the parent (RelativeLayout) cannot size itself based on the size and overall layout of its children (ImageViews) if the children are positioned relative to the size of the parent (RelativeLayout). The result is a circular dependency which cannot be resolved.

You'll either need to change how the RelativeLayout is sized, or position the ImageViews relative to a sibling view (e.g. one of the ImageViews) instead of being positioned relative to the parent RelativeLayout.

Comment: ... or use a GridLayout.

Answer (score 2):

Just access it directly with its ID.
Change the line to:

```
blueX = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.blueXTopLeft);
```

and do the similar thing with other related variables and it will then work.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. Now it calls a `ClassCastException` on the previous section of code where I initialize the blueX, greyX,...

Comment: Make sure that the blueX is declared as `ImageView blueX;` because ClassCastException is thrown only when one tries to cast the type of class into something which it isn't declared to be or which isn't in the inheritance hierarchy as its parent.

Comment: It is like that. That's how I declared it. I'm honestly really confused about why this could be happening.

Comment: No one's denying the fact that you are honestly confused about this situation. :D That's why you asked the question. Why don't you edit the above program and show me the whole Activity class? And also mention the XML file's name where you have kept all this layout, if it isn't in the activity_main.xml.

Comment: Alright I put up the entire activity class. Also, the layout is activity_main, which is also included above. Thank You.

Comment: Then its kind of strange. I have used the findViewById method many times like this, and never encountered any problems. Try to see where the error is happening in your code again, and try to debug those areas using logs. NullPointerExceptions are common, and once you debug it, you'll see where the error actually lies.

Comment: I experimented a bit, and now it's inflating the layout without crashing, but the icons are **still** not invisible. They all show up on top of each other; it's as if the setVisibility methods aren't even being called. Here's my updated Activity class above.

Comment: You might want to use Project -> Clean when you get unexpected ClassCastExceptions with Views. Always works for me.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, have you tried doing a clean on your project? your R.java could be a little messed up. Project>Clean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

**activity_main:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:minHeight="20dp"
android:minWidth="20dp" >

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/gameBoard"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:contentDescription="@string/gameboard"
  android:src="@drawable/gameboard" />

<RelativeLayout
  android:id="@+id/squareOneLayout"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginBottom="290dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="220dp"
  android:layout_marginTop="70dp" >

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/squareOne"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="288dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="219dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/top_left"
    android:onClick="squareOneClick"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_button" />

<!-- Top-left images -->

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/blueOTopLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/greyOTopLeft"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/piece_o" 
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/greyOTopLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/piece_o_grey" 
    android:visibility="invisible"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/greyXTopLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blueOTopLeft"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/piece_x_grey" 
    android:visibility="invisible"
   />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/blueXTopLeft"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/blueOTopLeft"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/piece_x" 
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
  </RelativeLayout>

  ... <!-- rest of xml -->

  </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.scopelyapplication.tictactoe;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    public class TicTacToeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String LOGTAG = "TicTacToeActivity";
    private ModelComputerGameHelper comHelp;

    boolean humanIsX;

    RelativeLayout layout;
    ImageView blueX, greyX, blueO, greyO;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

layout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

Log.d(LOGTAG, "onCreate");

//Set up action bar
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
Log.d(LOGTAG, "set action bar");

//Initialize X's and O's
blueX = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.blueXTopLeft);
greyX = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.greyXTopLeft);
blueO = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.blueOTopLeft);
greyO = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.greyOTopLeft);
Log.d(LOGTAG, "X's and O's initialized");



Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
boolean gameIsPVP = extras.getBoolean("gameIsPVP");
humanIsX = extras.getBoolean("humanIsX");

if (gameIsPVP) {
    ; //in progress
} else {
    startComputerGame(humanIsX);
}
}

public void squareOneClick(View imageView) {

char humanPlayer = ' ';
if (humanIsX) {
    humanPlayer = 'X';
} else {
    humanPlayer = 'O';
}
comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 0);
if (humanPlayer == 'X') {
    blueX.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    blueO.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

 updateBoard();
 }
 public void squareTwoClick(View imageView) {

char humanPlayer = ' ';
if (humanIsX) {
    humanPlayer = 'X';
}
else {
    humanPlayer = 'O';
}
comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 1);
updateBoard();
}
public void squareThreeClick(View imageView) {

char humanPlayer = ' ';
if (humanIsX) {
    humanPlayer = 'X';
}
else {
    humanPlayer = 'O';
}
comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 2);
updateBoard();
}
public void squareFourClick(View imageView) {

char humanPlayer = ' ';
if (humanIsX) {
    humanPlayer = 'X';
}
else {
    humanPlayer = 'O';
}
comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 3);
updateBoard();
}
public void squareFiveClick(View imageView) {

char humanPlayer = ' ';
if (humanIsX) {
    humanPlayer = 'X';
}
else {
    humanPlayer = 'O';
}
comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 4);
updateBoard();
}
public void squareSixClick(View imageView) {

char humanPlayer = ' ';
if (humanIsX) {
    humanPlayer = 'X';
}
else {
    humanPlayer = 'O';
}
 comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 5);
 updateBoard();
 }
public void squareSevenClick(View imageView) {

char humanPlayer = ' ';
if (humanIsX) {
    humanPlayer = 'X';
}
else {
    humanPlayer = 'O';
}
comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 6);
updateBoard();
}
public void squareEightClick(View imageView) {

char humanPlayer = ' ';
if (humanIsX) {
    humanPlayer = 'X';
}
else {
    humanPlayer = 'O';
}
comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 7);
updateBoard();
}
public void squareNineClick(View imageView) {

char humanPlayer = ' ';
if (humanIsX) {
    humanPlayer = 'X';
}
else {
    humanPlayer = 'O';
}
comHelp.makeMove(humanPlayer, 8);
 updateBoard();
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(this, PickerActivity.class));
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void startComputerGame(boolean isHumanX) {
Log.d(LOGTAG, "startComputerGame");
comHelp = new ModelComputerGameHelper(isHumanX);
 updateBoard();
 }

public void updateBoard() {
//in progress. connects startComputerGame and Clicks with Visuals.

}

}
```